# How do I use the 'Evaluate Javascript' function in Robotframework?

Tags: javascript, python, robotframework

I recently updated some outdated Robotframework libraries and found that the 'Execute Javascript' function from the Browser Library was deprecated and deleted, to be replaced with 'Evaluate Javascript'. After having read the description I tried adjusting the tests that were given to me to work with it, but to no avail.
This was the old, deprecated code:

```
${value}    Evaluate Javascript document.querySelector("score_Id").innerHTML.
```

This gave the ${value} the '3.9' from this element:
3.9

I attempted to adjust my code to the following:

`${value}   Evaluate Javascript     score_Id    document.innerHTML`.
This didn't work, as it returned an empty value. so I tried multiple variations:

```
${value}    Evaluate Javascript     score_Id    document.textContent
${value}    Evaluate Javascript     score_Id    document.getElementById.textContent
${value}    Evaluate Javascript     score_Id    document.querySelector().innerHTML
${value}    Evaluate Javascript     score_Id    innerHTML
```

All of these do not work.

I'm a bit stuck on what to do next. I don't have colleagues to ask about and I'm relatively new to all of this. I also tried a simple 'Get Text' function from the Browser Library:

```
${value}    Get Text    //*[@id="score_Id"]
```

But this resulted in the following:
`FAIL : Error: elementHandle.innerText: Error: Node is not an HTMLElement`
Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
${value}    Evaluate JavaScript    id=scoreId    (elem) => elem.innerHTML
```